# How to remove tooltips in minimized menu in Sencha ExtJS 6?

Tags: extjs

There is a sample slide menu with items in it. When we minimize menu, there are tooltips if we hover the items. How to remove these tooltips?

Comment: Sample http://codepen.io/rinatoptimus/pen/BKwLrN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [`onToolStripMouseOver`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.list.Tree-method-onToolStripMouseOver) with an empty function.

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGdgpG

---

(You'll might want to override [`onToolStripClick`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.list.Tree-method-onToolStripClick) too so the floating element will not appear when clicking)